# How can I optimize my code to stop sending GET requests constantly?

Tags: reactjs

I am using the Yelp Fusion API to get a list of restaurants from Yelp. However, I am always constantly sending a GET request and I am not sure what is going on or how to fix it. I have tried React.memo and useCallback. I think the problem lies within how I am making the call rather than my component rerendering.

**Here is where I send a GET request**

```
  // Function for accessing Yelp Fusion API
  const yelpFusionSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await yelp.get('/businesses/search', {
        params: {
          term: food,
          location: location
        }
      })
      // Saving our results, getting first 5 restaurants,
      // and turning off our loading screen
      setYelpResults({businesses: response.data.businesses.splice(0, 5)});
      setEnableLoading(1);
    }
    catch (error) {
      setEnableLoading(2);
    }
  };
```

**This is where I use axios.**

```
// Our Yelp Fusion code that sends a GET request
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: `${'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'}https://api.yelp.com/v3`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${KEY}`
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling that function within your functional component and that function sets a state of that component, so it re-renders. Then the function is executed again, sets state, re-renders and so on...

What you need to do is to wrap that API call inside a:

```
useEffect(() => {}, [])
```

Since you probably want to call it one time. See [useEffect doc here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. I am getting this warning though:

"React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'food', 'location', and 'setYelpResults'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'setYelpResults' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback".


I am kind of confused though, because I only want it to run on initial render so why would I need to put those values in there?

Comment: There are two ways of fixing that, you could just create that function being called inside the `useEffect` or just add those variables into the dependency array (the second param of the `useEffect` function). It's intended to provent bugs, you should always do what it says. Other ways of fixing is using `useCallback` if you want to use that function multiple times in and outside the `useEffect`

Comment: I want to but I don't see it as an option for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things either use a button to get the list of restaurants because you are firing your function again and again.

```
const yelpFusionSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await yelp.get('/businesses/search', {
        params: {
          term: food,
          location: location
        }
      })
```

1. Use a button instead maybe so once that button is clicked function is fired.

   ```
   <button onClick={yelpFusionSearch} />Load More Restaurants </button>
   ```
2. Use your fuction inside useEffect method which will load 5 restaurants once the page renders

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      const yelpFusionSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await yelp.get('/businesses/search', {
        params: {
          term: food,
          location: location
        }
      })

   }, [])
   ```